# Ionic item with left and right aligned text

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I have an ionic item in an ionic list. What is the best way to left align the first text and right align the second text?

```
  <div class="item">
    <span>first</span>
    <span>second</span>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This can be done using basic CSS properties. there is nothing specic about ionic here. This can be done using `float:left` and `float:right` properties.

Still for your reference, you can go through this [link](https://css-tricks.com/left-align-and-right-align-text-on-the-same-line/).

Comment: Awesome! I am attaching the changes I did so that others who find this post can find it. I added this to my CSS document: .alignleft {
 float: left;
}
.alignright {
 float: right;
} and then changed my HTML to this       <div class="item">
        <span class="alignleft">first</span>
        <span class="alignright">second</span>
      </div>

Answer (score 8):

In ionic 2 just use

**text-left,text-right**

```
<div class="item">
    <span text-left>first</span>
    <span text-right>second</span>
</div>
```

Read More :- 
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/typography.scss

Comment: Is it removed in ionic 4?

Answer (score 5):

With Ionic 3 the above answers did not work. With ion-items you can simply leave the left text untouched because it is left-aligned by default. With the text that you want to right-align, simply use the item-end decorator like this:

```
<ion-item>
     Name <span item-end>Zack</span>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: for ionic 3.  other example is not working in ionic 3

Answer (score 2):

You also use ionic's class and attribute to do that. For exemple

```
<div class="item row">
   <span align="right" class="col col-50">first</span>
   <span align="left" class="col col-50">second</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

With Ionic 2 & above, you can use **Element Placement** Attributes like `float-left` or `float-right` on your HTML elements instead of adding properties like `float: left;` or `float: right;` on your scss

https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-utilities/#float-elements

```
<div class="item">
  <span float-left>first</span>
  <span float-right>second</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I use Ionic 3 and the best anwser I think is to use the ionic tags and attributes:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>
      this to the left
    </ion-label>
    <ion-label text-right>
      this to the right
    </ion-label>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use css "text-align" property to do that

```
<div class="item row">
  <span style="text-align:right" class="col col-50">first</span>
  <span style="text-align:left" class="col col-50">second</span>
</div>
```

Hope this fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

Ionic uses CSS Utilities. They provide their own way of aligning text.

```html
<div class="item">
  <span>first</span>
  <span>second</span>
</div>
```

More about CSS utilities at https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-utilities/#text-alignment