# Ionic 2 & ion-item with left & right text

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2

In an ionic 2 app I simply want to create a clickable `<ion-item>` button that has text on the left and right.  It's for a check viewer (date on left, amount on right).

This seems very simple, and on the surface it is.  As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802395/ionic-item-with-left-and-right-aligned-text) you can just use some CSS to push text left/right.  What I've found is that works well with most views (e.g. phones), but on an iPad the item is not displayed well.

Some examples of my code and resulting iPad visuals are below.  Is there a clean way to do this?

```
              <button ion-item *ngFor="let settlement of recentSettlements | slice:0:3" (click)="showSettlement(settlement)">
                <span class="floatLeft">{{settlement.checkDate.slice(0,10)}}</span>
                <span class="floatRight" [ngClass]="(settlement.checkTotal >= 0) ? 'positiveAmount' : 'negativeAmount'">${{settlement.checkTotal}}</span>            
              </button>
```

Or

```
              <button ion-item *ngFor="let settlement of recentSettlements | slice:0:3" (click)="showSettlement(settlement)">
                <ion-label item-start>{{settlement.checkDate.slice(0,10)}}</ion-label>
                <ion-label item-end [ngClass]="(settlement.checkTotal >= 0) ? 'positiveAmount' : 'negativeAmount'">${{settlement.checkTotal}}</ion-label>            
              </button>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did end up using `item-left` and `item-right`.  I had to use `<span>` tags, not `<div>` as suggested above, in order to keep things on the same line.

My other issue was simply leaving enough space for the content in ionic's responsive grid.  My thought was if an `ion-card` fit well on a phone, I should easily be able to fit 2-3 on a tablet.  Turns out that's not always the case, depending on the content.

So, if things get smashed on different form-factors, the grid setup likely needs to be adjusted.  Some common sense lacking on my part!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to touch css, you can do it via Ionic's own directives:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let n of whatever" (click)="doSmt(n)">
    <div item-left>Left</div>
    {{n.someProperty}}
    <div item-right>Right</div>
  </ion-item>

</ion-list>
```

From the docs: https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#icon-list